# configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to install Robocup simulator from https://sourceforge.net/projects/sserver/?source=typ_redirect . As mentioned in the README file in the folder to build it I have to execute /.configure but I get this error.

```
saurabh@saurabh-GL502VM:~/intelligent_systems/project/rcssserver-15.3.0$ ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/saurabh/intelligent_systems/project/rcssserver-15.3.0':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create ex
```

Now when I checked my g++ compiler.

```
saurabh@saurabh-GL502VM:~/intelligent_systems/project/rcssserver-15.3.0$ g++ -v
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install g++
```

But when I tried to install g++ compilier I got this:

```
saurabh@saurabh-GL502VM:~/intelligent_systems/project/rcssserver-15.3.0$ sudo apt install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cpp-4.8 libcloog-isl4 xserver-xorg-legacy
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

Now, what should I do to install the the simulator? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt-get` can find multiple versions of g++, and even install them side by side. But clearly "g++" on the command line must be a shortcut to only one of them. You can change that shortcut with `sudo update-alternatives --config g++`.

Comment: Hey! yes this will work but anyway it removed one of the g++ version. Now, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure g++ is in your PATH variable. `echo $PATH` to see if it at least contains `/bin:/usr/bin`.

Then try to `find / -name g++`, if you found it, add the containing folder to PATH.

If that doesn't help, try reinstall g++ `apt-get remove g++; apt-get install g++`

Comment: I have reinstalled g++ and the system was clashing due to two versions of g++ installed. So, I removed one of them and everything is fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the compiler version being used in configure command. I checked g++ version  by command g++ --version. It was showing 4.9.2. so I specified compiler as g++-4.9.2. but there no alias for command g++-4.9.2. the only compiler was available g++-4.9. so it check for g++ version exact command available by typing manually on command line.

Answer (score 0):

list all gcc installations and links

```
ls -la /usr/bin | grep gcc
```

first try `ls /usr/lib/gcc`, if which exists, try `ln -s /usr/lib/gcc /usr/bin/gcc`  `PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/gcc` and execute `./configure`  (if it's installed it will sure work!)

There was a noted issues with different linux distributions, first remove and reinstall g++

```
$: apt remove g++
$: apt install g++
```

search for gcc and add it if not output anything try to add it

```
$: which gcc
```

if found add it to PATH (either /usr/bin/gcc if the softlink made or /usr/lib/gcc straight away),

```
$: PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/gcc
```

if the result is nothing (might take a while) try, (here try to build your own, perhaps that works. Else)

```
$:find / -name gcc
```

usually, it will be /usr/lib/gcc,  if available, make a soft link to the location to /usr/bin/gcc

```
ln -s /**/*/gcc /usr/bin/gcc
```

run `./configure`

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error too when i was trying to build a project with `clang` with `libc++` . After some exploring through `config.log` file I've found that `libc++abi-9-dev` package is required which was missing in my system (rpm-based, deb package might be named slightly different). After installing the package above the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

If you are here to solve the same issue on Centos 6.10, please do

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
```

In my case I was just missing them